# Need a regular expression to keep domain

Tags: regex

I have some URLs:

```
google.com  
stack.bing.com  
yahoo.com/text/4378
yahoo.com/65456/4378/76576
```

How to remove URL with more than 2 `/` characters? After removing, it only has:

```
google.com  
stack.bing.com
```

How to do it with regular expressions?

In this link http://textmechanic.com/Remove-Lines-Containing.html, it has **Enable regular expression search** function. So, i want to use regular expression for it.

Comment: "*more than*" means that `yahoo.com/text/4378` should be returned

Comment: What about `http://www.google.com`?

Comment: Link doesn't answer above questions.

Comment: http://textmechanic.com/Remove-Lines-Containing.html, i want use it for this link

Comment: what about `yahoo.com/text/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex for matching URLs with less than 2 slashes excluding cases of `http://example`):

```
^(?!.*?\/[^\/\n]+\/).+$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sW3gV5/1)

Or you can inverse the regex for **removal**:

```
^(?=.*?\/[^\/\n]+\/).+$
```

Comment: How to remove URL with **more than** 2 / characters?

Comment: You keep the matches and leave non matching ones.

Comment: you have mentioned for less than 2 slashes. What about exactly 2 slashes?

Comment: Do you want to remove URLs with **exactly** 2 slashes?

Comment: Thanks It works but it removed " http:// google.com/ ". If I add "/" after google.com, it will remove that URL. How to avoid it ?

Comment: @HongAnh If it doesn't work don't [accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Also don't extend discussion in comments, ask a new question.

Comment: Do you want to keep `http://google.com/` even though it has 2 slashes?

Comment: @Unihedron: Answer has worked with stated question but as you suggested I would repeat same that extending the question from comments is not a fair practice. Question should clearly have all the requirements.

Comment: @HongAnh: To avoid removing `http://google.com/` you can use this regex: `^(?=[^\/\n]*\/[^\/\n]+\/).+$`

Comment: Work like a charm. Thank you for helping me, anubhava !